# np.ones(size, 'd') what does the 'd' do?

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

Following [this post](https://scipy-cookbook.readthedocs.io/items/SignalSmooth.html) I'm trying to implement a one-dimensional smoothing algorithm. When creating a flat window for a simple moving average the call is as follows:

```
w = numpy.ones(window_len, 'd')
```

which yields an array of float64 ones. If I omit the 'd' the result is the same. So what does this parameter do? More interestingly the [official documentation](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ones.html) does not list a second positional argument and the [implementation](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/v1.19.0/numpy/core/numeric.py#L144-L194) doesn't seem to accept one so I'm even a little confused the call above doesn't simply blow up in my face.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`d` is just the character code for a double-precision floating-point `dtype`. It's a key word argument but can also just be specified positionally:

```
numpy.ones(shape, dtype=None, order='C')
```

Find more on numpy's datatypes in [Data type objects (dtype)](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/arrays.dtypes.html)

Answer (score 1):

```
numpy.ones(shape, dtype=None, order='C')
```

Parameters

```
shapeint or sequence of ints

    Shape of the new array, e.g., (2, 3) or 2.
dtypedata-type, optional

    The desired data-type for the array, e.g., numpy.int8. Default is numpy.float64.
order{‘C’, ‘F’}, optional, default: C

    Whether to store multi-dimensional data in row-major (C-style) or column-major (Fortran-style) order in memory.
```

full documentation at https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ones.html